# How do I get back a string value from a hashmap with enums?

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

I already have the following classes:

```
public enum Tile {
PT_Blue_1(1, 1, "Blue 1", "blue_1.jpg"),...;
//Constructor, getter and setter
```

A factoryClass with the following hashmap for all tiles:

```
public static HashMap<String, EnumSet<Tile>> getAllTiles() {
    HashMap<String, EnumSet<Tile>> htAllTiles = new HashMap<>();
    htAllTiles.put("Tiles", EnumSet.allOf(Tile.class));
    return htAllTiles;
}
```

I get `{Tiles=[Blue 1]}` back.

Now I want to convert it with an interface to an array to get back the imagename to add the images to a gameboard:

```
    public ITile[] getTilesToBoard() {
    ITile[] returnPath = Arrays.copyOf(this.hmTiles.values().toArray(), this.hmTiles.values().size(), ITile[].class);
    return returnPath;
}
```

Here I get now a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` and I don't know why. Can anyone see where the fault is?

At the end I want to use it to put it into a gridpane:

```
    ImageView[][] iV = new ImageView[COL][ROW];

    for (ITile tiles : model.gameBoard.getTilesToBoard()) {
      for(int i=0; i<COL; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<ROW;j++){
        iV[i][j] = new ImageView(ImageLoader.getImage(tiles.getTile().getPath()));
              gridPane.add(iV[i][j], i, j);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `ITile` and `Tile` are different

Comment: It looks like you are trying to copy the contents of a `Set<Tile>` to a `ITile[]` array. How are `Tile` and `ITile` related? Should `Tile` implement `ITile[]`?

Comment: ITile is an interface of tile and has only the following code:
`public interface ITile extends Comparable<ITile> {
    Tile getTile();   
}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an `EnumSet` as your value:

```
htAllTiles.put("Tiles", EnumSet.allOf(Tile.class));
```

And you are trying to assign the array `EnumSet`s to an array of `ITiles`.

```
ITile[] returnPath = Arrays.copyOf(this.hmTiles.values().toArray(), this.hmTiles.values().size(), ITile[].class);
```

Here `hmTiles.values()` is giving you collection EnumSets back and not a collection of your enum values.

You will have to interate over the EnumSet before you can add the values to the array. Try something like this:

```
public ITile[] getTilesToBoard() {
    ArrayList<ITiles> returnPath = new ArrayList<>();
    for (EnumSet<Tile> tiles : this.hmTiles.values()) {
        for (Tile tile : tiles) {
            returnPath.add(tile);
        }
    }
    return returnPath.toArray(new ITiles[returnPath.size()]);
}
```

PS: Also, note that [collection.toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray()) returns an Object[], to get a specific type of array you need to use [collection.toArray(T[] a)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T[]))

Comment: I think your diagnosis is incorrect, because `toArray()` is called on `hmTiles.values()`, which yields an array of enum values, not a collection of EnumSets.

Comment: @Wiebe Have you tried running it? `map.values()` returns a collections of all the values in the map. e.g. if you get values for a Map<Integer, String> it will return a `Collection<String>`. Similarly, a `Map<String, EnumSet<Tile>>` will return a `Collection<EnumSet<Tile>>`.

Comment: Oops I think you're right, it seems logical that `hmTiles` is the Map and not the EnumSet.

Comment: That solution works fine for me with `returnPath.addAll(tiles.stream().map(Tile::getPath).collect(Collectors.toList()));` but I still get a  `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`. 
I read that I want to store a wrong type of object into an array. Do I have to change something?

Comment: @gjasula I assume that your returnPath is a list of Tiles, and your are using map tile.getPath, which I'd guess is a string. You can't add strings to a list of Tiles.

Comment: @Suraj Bajaj: so I have to change the ArrayList to something else to get the Strings back?

Comment: If you want strings, you'll obviously need a list of strings. Try the code I gave you and if you want strings instead of .add(tile) use .add(tile.getPath()). If you debug and trace step by step, you'll understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried to do, but I have to change then  `ArrayList<ITiles>` to `ArrayList<String>`, because i need the strings for my gameboard and not the tiles as objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `Tile` does not implement `ITile`. Here is a simplified snippet that works:

```
interface ITile {}

public enum Tile implements ITile {
    one, two, three;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnumSet tiles = EnumSet.allOf(Tile.class);
    ITile[] iTiles = Arrays.copyOf(tiles.toArray(), 2, ITile[].class);
    System.out.println(iTiles[0]);
}
```